# Can I compute cross correlation after decomposition?

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, trend, cross-correlation

Given two time series within the same time period, I can use the `ccf` function in `R` to compute a notion of similarity of these time series. What I am wondering is this - can I compute the cross correlation on the trend line obtained after using time decomposition function such as `stl`?

Time series decomposition is known to decompose a given series into its trend line, seasonal component and the error so by removing the error, would we get a better sense of cross correlation? So in short, my question is this: ***Is cross correlation of the trend line better than cross correlating raw timeseries?***

I tried explaining what I had done in the picture that follows. In the cross correlation graph that I obtained, it indicates a high value at t=0.

[image]